# Download videos from the Internet in VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

please tell me. I have a link to the video. I have a VideoView. He plays some video formats. How can I play the video from the Internet to another format? how to decode it? or are there other ways?

```
package com.example.MyVideo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    private Button btn;
    private VideoView vv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.button:
                vv.setVideoURI(link);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to view the url directly in videoview, use like this:

```
 VideoView mVideoView;
 MediaController mcon;
 String videourl="http://ww.abc.com/a";
 mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
 mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videourl));
 mVideoView.start();
```

If you want to download videos from url and save in sd card, better use `webview` and
`WeViewClient` handles the url. See this tutorial

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/11/download-file-videoaudiotext-through.html

Comment: your code differs from mine? except lines mVideoView.start (); 
which still does not work? and why should MediaController mcon; if you do not use it anywhere?

Comment: it's optional if you need  to handle controllers orelse no need.whether you are testing in emulator or real device? @user3350266

Comment: add this..mVideoView.requestFocus(); and also check whether you have given internet permission in manifest too.surely will work @user3350266

Comment: I'm trying to download video format flv. format is not supported. how to change it?

Comment: flv will not work in android.use swf and moreover if you want to play swf in videoview, it won't work. swf will support only in webview. No other choice means convert that swf to mp4/3gp or supported android format and make it to play in videoview. @user3350266

Comment: so I'm asking. how can I play flv? the same as it's done. I think that the video is converted to the correct format. but how to do it?